# Convert a char ' ' or newline to a string

Tags: c++, stringstream

My goal is to convert `' '` into `" "`, and `'\n'` into `"\n"`

The code below works for general cases, but not with spaces and `'\n'`. Because the `>>` and `<<` operators do not take in `' '` and `'\n'`s.

```
std::string stringFromChar(char a) {
    std::stringstream ss(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out | std::stringstream::binary);
    std::string s;
    ss << a;
    ss >> s;
    return s;
}
```

I thought by using `std::stringstream::binary`, it uses a binary number for both reading and writing. Thus, preserving the character, without losing spaces or newlines.

I found that while `a` is `' '`, `s` turns out to be `""`.

I know a way to solve this:

```
std::string stringFromChar(char a) {
    std::stringstream ss(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out | std::stringstream::binary);
    std::string s;
    ss << a;
    s = ss.str();
    return s;
}
```

Is it true that it doesn't take away the spaces or newline while reading, but they get deleted while writing? And why doesn't using binary with stringstream work?

Also, I tried using ss >> std::noskipws >> s As in:

```
std::string stringFromChar(char a) {
    std::stringstream ss(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out | std::stringstream::binary);
    std::string s;
    ss << a;
    ss >> std::noskipws >> s;
    return s;
}
```

It also didn't work. Why? s is still returned as "".

Answer (score 2):

Don't make it so complex:

```
std::string stringFromChar(char a)
{
    return std::string(1,a);
}
```

As a secondary note:
The only thing that `std::ios::binary` does is turn on binary mode. Binary mode stops the conversion of '\n' to/from the line termination sequence (which is a platform specific sequence of characters defined as the end of line).

Comment: Yeah. Simple *and* fast. (Unnecessary use of `std::stringstream` just makes things slower.)

Comment: So then '\n' is regarded as a char of value 10 (which is a newline in ASCII code), right? "Binary mode stops the conversion of '\n' to/from the line termination sequence", so what is it passed around as? As '\n' still instead of the termination sequence?

Comment: Yes. In binary mode there is no conversion. so 10 => 10 in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

Aurrgh, this all seems awfully complicated...

Why not try this:

```
std::string stringFromChar(char a) {
    return std::string( &a, 1 );
}
```

Or this:

```
std::string stringFromChar(char a) {
    char tmp[2] = { a, 0 };
    return std::string(tmp);
}
```

**Edit**: If you insist on using streams, try this:

```
std::string stringFromChar(char a) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.put(a);
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Those all works. But my questions aren't answered. :( But thanks a lot!! :D

Comment: @YatingSheng I think the problem is that when you read a string using `>>` operator, the end of the string is always considered to be bounded by whitespace.  So regardless of whether the `skipws` flag is set, you will get an empty string because the read operation did not find a string.  If you instead use the `str()` member to access the internal string (as you are supposed to do when working with stringstreams), you should have no such issues.

Answer (score 0):

use ss.get(a) to get each of  the characters from the stream without skipping spaces and new line feeds where a is of type char